# PUT and DELETE in RETROFIT

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Hi everyone i do have aserver with data that looks like this 
    someurl/jasonfakeAPI/tracks

```
    {
      "id": "7fmVIBMLYiXRtTFOlxv90i"
    }
```

and i want to make a PUT and DELETE requests to my android code 
i made the requests like this

```
    @PUT("tracks")
    Call<likeDislike> putlike(@Body likeDislike like);

    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "tracks", hasBody = true)
    Call<likeDislike> deletelike(@Body likeDislike like);
```

and in my code i implemented the functions like this but the delete i got a 404 i need help with this issue and are my methods correct ?

`
            private void putlike() {

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("jasonfakeAPI/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

        likeDislike likee=new likeDislike("ubvjksdbvxnudb");
        Call<likeDislike> likeee = jsonPlaceHolderApi.putlike(likee);

        likeee.enqueue(new Callback<likeDislike>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<likeDislike> call, Response<likeDislike> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                likeDislike likeResponse = response.body();
                String content = "";
                content += "Code:" + response.code()+"\n";
                content += "ID: " + likeResponse.getId() + "\n";
                textViewResult.setText(content);

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<likeDislike> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

//    private void deletelike() {
//
//        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
//                .baseUrl("jasonfakeAPI/")
//                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
//                .build();
//        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
//
//
//        Call<Void> likeee = jsonPlaceHolderApi.deletelike("7fmVIBMLYiXRtTFOlxv90i");
//
//        likeee.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
//                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
//                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
//            }
//        });
//
//    }
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This annotation can also used for sending DELETE with a request body:

```
interface Service {
   @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "remove/", hasBody = true)
   Call<ResponseBody> deleteObject(@Body RequestBody object);
 }
```

Reference : https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/HTTP.html

Comment: could you plz specify how in my case i would add it cause i seem to tried something like that but i do get 404 and 500 eror